# Uploading Files with Flask

Tags: python-3.x, file-upload, flask

I am building a form in Flask that has 2 FileFields in the form, however, I am unable to upload the files unless I use wtf.quick_form to render my html page.

I have tried to place the file upload into a class so it can be re-used, however, the field data is passed as a string.

My code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import FileField, SubmitField
import wtforms.validators

from flask import Flask, request, url_for, redirect
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

import os

class ChangeForm(FlaskForm):

    bizAuth = FileField('Additional Sign-off:')
    newDoc = FileField('Training/Documentation')
    submit = SubmitField('Save')


@app.route('/change', methods=['GET','POST'])
def form():

    if chgForm.validate_on_submit():

        fUp = File_Upload() # File Upload class - detailed below.
        chgForm = ChangeForm()

        bizAuth = chgForm.bizAuth.data
        chgDetail['bizAuth'] = fUp.upload(bizAuth)

        newDoc = chgForm.newDoc.data
        chgDetail['newDoc'] = fUp.upload(newDoc)


class File_Upload():

    def allowed_files(self, fileName):

        ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = self.allowed_files_lookup()

        return '.' in fileName and fileName.rsplit('.',1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

    def upload(self, fileName):

        f = fileName.filename

        if f == '':
            return 'NULL'

        elif f and self.allowed_files(f):

            file = secure_filename(f)
            fileName.save(os.path.join(config['src_dir'],'Normal Changes Docs\\' + f))

        return str(os.path.join(config['src_dir'],'Normal Changes Docs\\' + f))
```

My HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='chgForm-hiding.css') }}">

    {% block title %}Change Process{% endblock %}

</head>

 <body>

{% block page_content %}
    <form>
        <div class="Biz_Auth">
            {{form.bizAuth.label}}
            {{form.bizAuth}}
        </div>

        <div class="new-doc">
            {{form.newDoc.label}}
            {{form.newDoc}}
        </div>
        {{form.submit}}
    </form>
{% endblock %}

</body>
```

If anyone can help I would be very grateful. Many of the examples I have seen don't separate the upload function out in the manner I have, and rely on using quick_form to render the page or specific html tags hardcoded into their upload function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following changes needed to be made :

Change 1

```
if request.method == "POST" and chgForm.validate_on_submit():
    bizAuth = chgForm.bizAuth.data
    chgDetail['bizAuth'] = fUp.upload(bizAuth)

    newDoc = chgForm.newDoc.data
    chgDetail['newDoc'] = fUp.upload(newDoc)
```

Change 2

`<form action="{{ url_for('form') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Change 3

Add the following in the form tag, `{{ form.csrf_token }}`

Below is a sample python script with above changes,

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import FileField, SubmitField
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flask import request
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = './uploads'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'catchmeifyoucan'


class ChangeForm(FlaskForm):
    bizAuth = FileField('Additional Sign-off:')
    newDoc = FileField('Training/Documentation')
    submit = SubmitField('Save')


@app.route('/change', methods=['GET','POST'])
def form():
    fUp = FileUpload()  # File Upload class - detailed below.
    chgForm = ChangeForm()
    chgDetail = dict()

    # Change 1
    if request.method == "POST" and chgForm.validate_on_submit():
        bizAuth = chgForm.bizAuth.data
        chgDetail['bizAuth'] = fUp.upload(bizAuth)

        newDoc = chgForm.newDoc.data
        chgDetail['newDoc'] = fUp.upload(newDoc)

    return render_template('index.html', form=chgForm)


class FileUpload():

    def allowed_files(self, file_name):
        allowed_extensions = ['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif']
        return '.' in file_name and file_name.rsplit('.',1)[1].lower() in allowed_extensions

    def upload(self, file):
        file_name = file.filename
        if file_name == '':
            return 'NULL'

        elif file_name and self.allowed_files(file_name):
            secure_file_name = secure_filename(file_name)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],'Normal Changes Docs\\' + secure_file_name))

        return str(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],'Normal Changes Docs\\' + secure_file_name))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="{{ url_for('form') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.bizAuth.label }}
    {{ form.bizAuth }}
    {{ form.newDoc.label }}
    {{ form.newDoc }}
    {{ form.submit }}
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have made a change as I failed to include something in my code, which was the validate_on_submit() if statement, which is needed for another field in my application.

However, the code you provided does in fact work and resolve my issue, to be able to upload files. Would you know how I could get this to work with validate_on_submit()??

Comment: change `if request.method == "POST":` to `if request.method == "POST" and chgForm.validate_on_submit():` and in html template, inside the form tag add `{{ form.csrf_token }}`. I hope this helps

Comment: I have edited the solution to reflect the changes. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hey George, I was working it through but marked as the right answer and upvoted. Thanks for your help